Galerkin Method - Why does integration-by-parts eliminate need to enforce Neumann boundaries?
Disclaimer: I have not taken any class in functional analysis and the only class I have ever taken in differential equations is at the barest-bones introductory level.
From what I know of the Galerkin method, it is about approximating $u$, to a invertible linear system $Au=f$, as a vector in some subspace of the original square-integrable function space that $u$ resides in; aka, find the vector $\hat{u}$ in some subspace $X$ such that $(f-A\hat{u}) \perp X$.
Obviously, if I want to approximate $u$ as the linear combination of some set of functions $\psi_n$, I need to make sure that those functions satisfy the vector space axioms (because otherwise the functions would not span a vector space). This makes dealing with boundary conditions difficult, because nonhomogeneous boundary conditions are not preserved under arbitrary linear combinations.
However, this can be ameliorated by approximating $u$ as the sum of a a vector in a trial space that satisfies the homogeneous version of the boundary conditions plus some function that satisfies the nonhomogeneous boundary conditions. Of course, if both nonhomogeneous Dirichlet and Neumann boundary conditions are present, this becomes complicated to implement.
For differential equations, it appears that using integration-by-parts allows us to neglect enforcing Neumann boundary conditions on our trial space, as claimed in places like page 10 of
Zahr's lecture notes on weighted residual methods: https://mjzahr.github.io/content/ame40541/spr20/ch03-wres-solo.pdf
Zahr makes the claim:

"Since the [weak formulation] incorporates the natural BCs, the trial space does not have to be restricted to functions that satisfy the natural BCs (only essential BCs)"

Why is this the case? If we have a basis $\{\psi_n\}$ for our trial space, why is it that integration-by-parts ensures that the coefficients for each basis will still result in the linear combination respecting Neumann boundary conditions even if we don't enforce such a requirement on the trial space?
Meanwhile, the answerer of this related StackExchange question: How to solve a boundary value problem with Neumann Boundary conditions using the Finite Element Method
...claims the following:

The weird trick with Neumann boundary conditions is to simply replace $u′(1)$ in the equation with what the BVP wants it to be (so $0$ in your case), rather than forcing $u′(1)$ to actually be $0$. There are a bunch of ways to support why this is the right way to do things, but as a newcomer it is easier to just think of it as a weird trick.

What exactly are those "bunch of ways to support why this is the right way to do things"??? And on a related note, is there a way to generalize this beyond (a sum of) differential operators, or is this trick exclusive to differential equations?

Related question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/357170/using-galerkin-method-for-pde-with-neumann-boundary-condition
